# c++ meta-function returning a type

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I am trying to create a meta-function that returns a type. The inspiration came from the first accepted answer in [C++ meta-function over templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60365244/c-meta-function-over-templates) . I want my meta-function to return the type `char` and then I want to use that output to create a char variable. I believe my template works but I have no idea how to check the output. I was unable to print it. How do I check what the returned type is? How do I use that returned type to create a variable?

This is a summarized version of my code:

```
template<typename T> struct AA;
// allow for shorter syntax - decl<...>
template<typename T> using decl = typename AA<T>::result;

// char termination
template<ExprType eType>
struct AA<Expr<eType>> { using result = char; };

...other templates that specialize and allow for recursion

int main()
{
    decl<..many args..> typee;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to find a way to check the type of `typee`?

Comment: @NathanOliver I am hoping that `typee` is itself a type and can be used for creating a variable.

Comment: `typee` is a object, not a type.  That said, you can use it to get its type using `decltype` like `decl<..many args..> typee; decltype(typee) antother_object;`

Comment: Then you seem to want `using typee = decl<..many args..>`.

Comment: Off topic: your `struct AA` is usually called "(custom) type trait", in C++ world; not "meta function".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My usual method is to declare a dummy class template:

```
template <class...>
struct check_type;
```

And use it in a way that triggers an error:

```
check_type<decltype(typee)>{};
```

This way the type of whatever I passed appears in the compiler's output:

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:8:18: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct check_type<int>'
    8 |  check_type<int>{};
      |                  ^
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check type with

`static_assert(std::is_same_v<char, decl</*..many args..*/>>)`

And for debugging, you might use

```
template <typename> struct Debug; /* No definition */

Debug<decl</*..many args..*/>> d; // Error similar to: No definition for Debug<char>
```